# Can we settle this STD vs SEM debate once and for all?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

OK, I AM getting tired of seeing the SEM used simply as a means of reducing the size of error bars.  If the SEM is a measure of the precision of a mean from a sample, then in my mind one cannot generate an SEM from one mean.  One needs many means to estimate the precision of the "population mean"  SO, the only time I ever used the SEM was when I calculated many sample means (each with replicates of course to generate a mean) and then calculated the STD of the average of those means to use in the equation SEM = STD/sqrt of n which in my case was the number of individual sample means.

To me one should show the STD of a representative experiment (itself a somewhat ambiguous and often inaccurate phrase) and dispense with the SEM.  I just see zero utility in its use from a SINGLE sample mean.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The SE model is for questions that have answers, not a discussion forum (that's what chat is for). This isn't a question at all, but at best a thesis of sorts, and something of a rant.

Comment: Yup.  Too bad.  Just ignore and move on if you have an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that with STD you mean standard deviation and with SEM you mean the standard error. The two just measure different things: the standard deviation just measures how much the obervations in your sample are appart from each other. The standard error measures the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the statistic. The first is purely descriptive, the latter is there to do inference. Both can be valid aims for research. So I don't see why there is a debate: You can use either without problems as long as you make sure that you are showing the things you want to show and your audience understands that.

From your question I suspect that the real problem is that you have trouble understanding how one can estimate the standard error of the sampling distribution from just one sample. The background there is the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

What I often find useful to get an initial idea about the logic is to create a simulation. For example create many draws of size 100 each from a standard normal distribution, compute the mean in each of these and collect those means. They are an estimate of the sampling distribution. Now see if the mean of that sampling distribution is close to the mean in the population (0) and the standard deviation of the sampling distribution (the standard error) is close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}=0.1$. Here is the output of such a simulation in Stata:

```
. clear all

. set more off

. set seed 12345

. program define sim
  1.         drop _all
  2.         set obs 100
  3.         gen x = rnormal()
  4.         sum x, meanonly
  5. end

. simulate m=r(mean), reps(10000) nodots : sim

      command:  sim
            m:  r(mean)


. sum m

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
           m |     10,000    .0013082      .10061   -.443326   .3668843
```

Comment: +1 for spotting the underlying confusion. A bit more commentary connecting the simulation results to SE and SDs in the single sample case might help the OP.

Comment: Sorry, the SEM means nothing to me from a single mean of replicates.  For example, I measure the height of 100 random people from Germany, I generate a mean.  That SINGLE mean can hardly be used to estimate its precision to the entire mean height of the world.  On the other hand, let's say I then do two more experiments (100 people from USA and 100 people from China).  Now I have three means.  The SEM now makes sense here because I have three means in which to estimate the error of the POPmean.

Comment: TO continue….not sure what discipline most readers are in, but I can assure all that in Biology, the SEM is grossly and inaccurately used to define a data set.  SEM does not measure dispersion.  That would be the STD.  In fact, I tell my students NOT to use SEM and to show their data as a scatterplot with the STD,  That means much more to me than SEM, which again,  has little to no meaning to me in biology.  regrets to the math and stat geeks!

Comment: Why are you so negative? I am just trying to help you understand what the logic behind the standard error is. Standard errors and standard deviations both have meaning, even in biology. They just mean different things. It is common to confuse the two, but the solution is not to ban one, but to understand what both mean and use the appropriate measure in each situation.